# Size of solutions in integer programming

Tags: ds.algorithms, integer-programming, convex-geometry, integer-lattice, convex-hull

Given a linear integer program $Ax\leq b$ with $A\in\mathbb Z^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb Z^m$ known is there a polynomial time algorithm to give tight upper bounds for $\log_2\|x\|_\infty$ and $\log_2\|x\|_2$ where $x\in\mathbb Z^n$ is unknown?